# Why isn't my Service stopping?

Tags: java, android, service

I am starting a service that listens for phone calls while running and it works great. When I press a button to stop the service it appears to be stopped, but still works. I wont even see it in the task manager. I've searched and tried different things with stopSelf() and onDestroy() etc., but no luck...

```
package org.example.mystuff;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {

public static boolean isRunning;
private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
private boolean mAllowRebind;
private int startId;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
      return MyService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    isRunning = true;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    this.startId = startId;
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
      return mAllowRebind;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent){

}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    stopSelf(startId);
    isRunning = false;
}
}
```

Here is how I start it in my MainActivity...

```
package org.example.mystuff;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Intent intent;
private TextView currentStatusTV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);
    currentStatusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentStatusTextView);
    checkServiceStatus();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    checkServiceStatus();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    checkServiceStatus();
}

@Override
public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    checkServiceStatus();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void startService(View view){
    startService(intent);
    Toast.makeText(this,  "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    currentStatusTV.setText(R.string.service_running);
    finish();
}

public void stopService(View view){
    stopService(intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    currentStatusTV.setText(R.string.service_stopped);  
}

public void checkServiceStatus(){
    if(MyService.isRunning){
        currentStatusTV.setText(R.string.service_running);
    } else {
        currentStatusTV.setText(R.string.service_stopped);
    }
}
}
```

I have two buttons on the MainActivity with onClick properties to call startService and stopService which in turns calls the actual start/stopServices of the Service.
Again, I have tried many other solutions on here, but nothing seems to work. I'm wondering if I missed something important elsewhere as I am new to Services.

Comment: Your code is correct. Just remove stopSelf() from onDestroy(). How do you know it doesn't stop?

Comment: When a phone call is dialed or answered it starts an activity. I only want it to do that while the service is running. When I press the stop button and exit the application the activity still starts up with the phone is used again. Also, I just added stopSelf() in my latest attempt, it didn't work before without it either.

Comment: It doesn't mean service is still running. You could also register activity to start on phone call in Android manifest file, for instance.

Comment: Ok, I just have classes that extend BroadcastReceiver and PhoneStateListener. Is there a chance that they just continue to listen after the Activities are finished and the service is stopped?

Comment: If they are registered in the manifest, then definitely they do.

Comment: Alright, I just tried something and it seemed to fix it. Thanks beworker you pointed me in the right direction! I used the PackageManager to disable the receiver when I stopped the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to beworker for pointing me in the right direction on this one. I was stopping my service just fine, but my BroadcastReceiver was still registered in my AndroidManifest.xml and I wasn't taking care of that. So I used PackageManager to enable and disable the receiver in my MainActivity.

To stop I added this to stopService():

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, CallReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, 
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

To enable I used: `PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED` inside of startService().